How to extend laptop screen to 2 monitors with 1 HDMI port only? USB C port, but when connected it says the display connection might be limited

Laptop: HP Pavilion x360-14-dh1179tu
Monitor: Benq GW3290QT 31.5"

I have a laptop with one HDMI output and I have 2 monitors with HDMI input how do I extend multiple screens to my monitors what device should I buy to enable one HDMI to extend to 2 monitors?
I have a USB C port, but when connected it says "Display connection might be limited. Make sure the DisplayPort device you're connecting to is supported by your PC".And I also have 2 USB ports.

USB hub with HDMI output. Ideally a USB-C one.

it says the Display connection might be limited Care to share with us the exact message? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

The exact message when I use the USB C port is: Display connection might be limited. Make sure the DisplayPort device you're connecting to is supported by your PC.

https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Pavilion-x360-alt-mode/td-p/6597514 Mystery solved! That message is because your USB-C does NOT support video mode.

The HP Pavilion x360-14-dh1179tu has an USB-C for data only, no alternate video mode.
Source: https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Pavilion-x360-alt-mode/td-p/6597514
